# How to remove jquery scrollfix class upon a narrow viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [ScrollFix](https://github.com/ShiraNai7/jquery-scrollfix) to fix my header upon scrolling.
Although it's working 100% fine, I want to disable / remove the class ( `.scroll-fix` ) that this script adds to my header `#header` to disable the ScrollFix function WHEN my viewport is below a width of 768px.

I know I can do it via media queries but to cut a long story short, it's just not working out and I think using a removeClass via javascript would obviously be the best choice... however after doing research online and attempting to do a removeClass with this script, I cannot seem to come right. I'm pretty sure it's quite simple.

NOTE: I am not at all good with javascript so I just end up guessing most of the time.

Here is my [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/075t5mto/)

I'd appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: `position:fixed` fixes you header ... the class specifies some extra params, so removing it or not, you will have header fixed until you did't remove inline added `position:fixed` or add an extra class overriding it

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly... you see I've tried everything I know CSS wise and it's creating weird problems even when I override some css properties that the scroll-fix adds, like display:none; or position: relative; etc etc... as mentioned in my question, I think the best practice would be to do the removeClass thing in ... $('#header').scrollFix(); ... which I've been trying to do but without success.

Comment: if you want to handle the problem by removing the class at least initialise the `scrollFix` setting `style` to `false` i.e. `$('#header').scrollFix(style: false);` because otherwise an inline `style="position:fixed"` wil be added, and removing the class won't help much, so that's why I proposed you to add extra class instead of removing ` .scroll-fix` and in the css of this call to override the `position:fixed`

Comment: Okay I understand that adding another class would do the trick (I didn't think of that TBH) ... now the thing is, I don't understand the `$('#header').scrollFix(style: false);` code ... when I use this code, other javascript plugins don't work ... if you go to https://jsfiddle.net/075t5mto/2/ ... you will see I've added a media query and a class `.no_scroll` but I don't know how to implement this into the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm answering my own question because it's been a few days and it looks like there's not much interest / help on this topic. I've decided to use an alternative method which works exactly the same way but the good thing about this method is that there's minimal jquery / javascript involved and it's relying more on CSS which has made it a lot easier to manipulate when using media queries.

See my [FIDDLE][1] and remember to resize the window in and out of 768px viewport to see the effect:

1) When the viewport is below 768px (mobile device mode), the sticky / fixed navigation **ISN'T** fixed upon scroll

2) When the viewport is above 768px (Desktop / laptop mode), the sticky / fixed navigation **IS** fixed upon scroll.

I hope this helps whoever desires the same effect.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/g38mzx1L/1/
```

Comment: I cannot understand why I cannot link the FIddle the same way as usual but the post section isn't allowing me to which is strange but nevertheless, the link is there